# Looking for Nonassociative Algebra notes

Tags: reference-request, nonassociative-algebras

I'm reading Shafer's book on nonassociative algebras, but it contains no exercises. Could you share with me some other references, especially course's notes?

Comment: Rather terse but potentially useful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.06392.pdf. (This focuses on the category theoretic aspects, which may not be what you're looking for.)

Comment: A legal online copy of Shafer's book can be found [at Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/25156/25156-pdf.pdf). (At least [I think it's legal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gutenberg#Copyright) - if someone says it's not, I'll delete this comment of course.)

Comment: I'm reading category theory too; thank you!